# Packages are not installed in proxmox 6.1 virtualbox

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox, proxmox

***Hello everybody ! I installed proxmox in a virtual machine (VirtualBox 6.1), and every time I try to install packages the debian or ceph knocks out the following errors:***

**It`s when l install ceph:**

```
 W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://download.proxmox.com/debian/ceph-nautilus/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.proxmox.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'enterprise.proxmox.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
start installation
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package ceph is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ceph-common
Package ceph-mds is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'ceph' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'ceph-mds' has no installation candidate
apt failed during ceph installation (25600)
```

**It`s when l update system:**

```
root@pve:~# apt-get update 
Err:1 https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve buster InRelease                                                                                 
  Temporary failure resolving 'enterprise.proxmox.com'
Err:2 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                                                                                              
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
Err:3 http://security.debian.org buster/updates InRelease                                                 
  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
Err:4 http://download.proxmox.com/debian/ceph-nautilus buster InRelease    
  Temporary failure resolving 'download.proxmox.com'
Err:5 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
Reading package lists... Done    
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://ftp.debian.org/debian/dists/buster-updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'ftp.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://security.debian.org/dists/buster/updates/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'security.debian.org'
W: Failed to fetch http://download.proxmox.com/debian/ceph-nautilus/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'download.proxmox.com'
W: Failed to fetch https://enterprise.proxmox.com/debian/pve/dists/buster/InRelease  Temporary failure resolving 'enterprise.proxmox.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

***If anyone knows how to solve this I will be very grateful for your help! Thanks.***

Answer (score 0):

you don't have a  proper network connection settings from that VM  (nat , bridge, gateway ? ), or name resolution inside (resolv.conf) ?